# How to use Multiple Delimiter in preg_split()

Tags: php, delimiter, preg-split

I have this preg_split function with the pattern to search for any `<br>`

However, I would like to add some more pattern to it besides `<br>`.

How can I do that with the current line of code below?

```
preg_split('/<br[^>]*>/i', $string, 25);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: PHPs `preg_split()` function only accepts a single pattern argument, not multiple. So you have to use the power of regular expressions to match your delimiters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPs preg_split() function only accepts a single pattern argument, not multiple. So you have to use the power of regular expressions to match your delimiters.

This would be an example:

```
preg_split('/(<br[^>]*>)|(<p[^>]*>)/i', $string, 25);
```

If matches on html line breaks *and/or* paragraph tags.

It is helpful to use a regex tool to test ones expressions. Either a local one or a web based service like https://regex101.com/

The above slips the example text

```
this is a <br> text
with line breaks <br /> and
stuff like <p>, correct?
```

like that:

```
Array
(
    [0] => this is a
    [1] =>  text
with line breaks
    [2] =>  and
stuff like
    [3] => , correct?
)
```

*Note however that for parsing html markup a DOM parser probably is the better alternative. You don't risk to stumble over escaped characters and the like...*